# How do you restart a void Start after an IF statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding myself a 2D little RPG game with very little experience in coding.
I finished my Turn-Based Combat but now I need to add an automatic restart after losing.

I figured it could easily be done by making void Start() start again and reset values I need but I sadly couldn't find any way to do it.

```
        if (enemyHealth <= 0)
    {
        wonlostPanel.SetActive(true);
        wonlostDisplay.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "You WON!";
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
    else if (playerHealth < 0) 
    {
        wonlostPanel.SetActive(true);
        wonlostDisplay.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "You Lost!";
        StopAllCoroutines();
        
    }
}
private void Start()
{
    enemyHealth = 100;
    playerHealth = 100;
    enemyState = "Preparing For Attack";
    playerDamage = 50;
    healPotions = 10;

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason just calling the function doesn't work?

Comment: Is there a reason just calling the function doesn't work?

Comment: clarify what you are doing to restart

Comment: If the playersHealth hits 0, i would want the void Start to do everything again as it did on the first frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice to call `Start()` method from any other method in the script even though you declared it as `public`, it's a default method called by Unity at the start of the game. What you can do is move all your code that's resetting the values into a new method and call it in both `Start()` method and when the player's health goes below `0`.

```cs
private void Start() => ResetValues();

private void ResetValues()
{
    enemyHealth = 100;
    playerHealth = 100;
    enemyState = "Preparing For Attack";
    playerDamage = 50;
    healPotions = 10;
}
```

```cs
else if (playerHealth < 0) 
{
    wonlostPanel.SetActive(true);
    wonlostDisplay.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "You Lost!";
    StopAllCoroutines();

    ResetValues();
}
```